# How do I remove the background color when the tab is active?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Anybody knows how to throw this annoying background-color when the tab is active? I tried with lot of solutions but I'm still having problems

```js
function TabsAndroid() {
  return (
    <TabAndroid.Navigator
      sceneAnimationEnabled={true}
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.primary }}
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => {
          let iconStr: string = "";
          if (route.name === "Tab1")
            return (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: "https://imgs.search.brave.com/70390jQSfVsjPzoOaHb96nE2lssrdYkr0HOVLKagutE/rs:fit:1024:1024:1/g:ce/aHR0cDovL2ljb25z/Lmljb25hcmNoaXZl/LmNvbS9pY29ucy9w/YW9tZWRpYS9zbWFs/bC1uLWZsYXQvMTAy/NC9zb2NpYWwtZmFj/ZWJvb2staWNvbi5w/bmc",
                }}
                style={{ width: 10, height: 20 }}
              />
            );
          if (route.name === "Tab2") iconStr = "T2";
          if (route.name === "StackNavigator") iconStr = "Stack";
          return <Text style={{ color }}>{iconStr}</Text>;
        },
      })}
      activeColor="#fff"
      inactiveColor="#ccc"
    >
      <TabAndroid.Screen
        name="Tab1"
        options={{ tabBarColor: "red" }}
        component={Tab1}
      />
      <TabAndroid.Screen name="Tab2" component={Tab2} />
      <TabAndroid.Screen name="StackNavigator" component={MyStack} />
    </TabAndroid.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I tried with oldest solutions, I only get to change the text color when the user clicks the tab, but dont for the icon

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the background color in screenOptions.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#screenoptions Try this:

```
            <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: "red",
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "blue",
            tabBarStyle: {
                 height: 55,
            },
            tabBarOptions: {
           style: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
            },
        }}>
```

Comment: I dony have that options, may you share me your package.json?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-forked-6xx8wn?file=/src/App.js check it sandbox example

Comment: package :- npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs